# Using Intent, to enable GPS doens't always work correctly. How do I fix

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps

The below code enables me to turn the user's GPS on and off at will but at times this doesn't work correctly, although the icon for GPS scanning will be at the top of the screen in the user's notification bar the ***GPS icon will not be highlighted***. Making verifications like (isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);) not detect whether or not GPS is enabled.

Code used to enable GPS:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
      intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
      sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: Why are you using an intent to turn on GPS?  Why not just request location updates?

Comment: How else would you do it? The GPS would still be required to be switched on wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

refer this link:
Its sdk version problem.
higher version doesnt support this intent.

http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2013/08/disable-gps-via-programatically-in.html